# Passing predicate as a parameter

Tags: c#, sqlite, predicate

I am trying to get only a certain number of elements by passing a predicate as a parameters. But I am getting the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable < Students.Entities>` to `bool`

```
var names = await Task.Run(() => Repository.GetWithNChildren(e => e.Entities.Take(offset)));


public List<T> GetWithNChildren(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null)
{
  var db = _factory.GetConnectionWithLock();
  using (db.Lock())
  {
      return db.GetAllWithChildren(predicate, true);
   }
 }
```

`GetAllWithChildren` is a method in the SQLite Class

```
namespace SQLiteNetExtensions.Extensions
{
    public static class ReadOperations
    {
        public static bool EnableRuntimeAssertions;

        public static T FindWithChildren<T>(this SQLiteConnection conn, object pk, bool recursive = false) where T : class;
        public static List<T> GetAllWithChildren<T>(this SQLiteConnection conn, Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, bool recursive = false) where T : class;
        public static void GetChild<T>(this SQLiteConnection conn, T element, string relationshipProperty, bool recursive = false);
        public static void GetChild<T>(this SQLiteConnection conn, T element, Expression<Func<T, object>> propertyExpression, bool recursive = false);
        public static void GetChild<T>(this SQLiteConnection conn, T element, PropertyInfo relationshipProperty, bool recursive = false);
        public static void GetChildren<T>(this SQLiteConnection conn, T element, bool recursive = false);
        public static T GetWithChildren<T>(this SQLiteConnection conn, object pk, bool recursive = false) where T : class;
    }
}
```

Comment: which line has the error

Comment: The first line has  an error

Comment: Obviously, the `IEnumerable<T>` returned by `.Take()` cannot be converted to `bool`. What is so surprising?

Comment: And what is the problem? You pass  e.Entities.Take(offset) that returns IEnumerable<Entity> and predicate must be an Expression returning bool

Comment: @NicoSchertler how to solve it?

Comment: Pass an actual predicate? Depends on what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

The value `Func<T, bool>` means a function that takes in `T` and returns `bool`.

The function `Take(int n)` takes in `IEnumerable<T>` and returns a `IEnumerable<T>` that has at most `n` members.

You need to change `e.Entities.Take(offset)` to something that returns a bool or switch `Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null` to `Expression<Func<T, U>> predicate = null` and change `GetAllWithChildren` to take in the same type.

Comment: once I change it to `<T,T>` and then `GetAllWithChilldren` complains because it only accepts `<T,bool>`, see my updated question

Comment: All I need is, not to get all items, only certain items (offset).

Answer (score 1):

The error is correct.
This expression:

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>>
```

means "I take an instance of T, and will return a boolean"

But you **don't** return a booelean:

```
e => e.Entities.Take(offset)
```

This is becuase 
`Take(..)` does not return boolean, but instead a IEnumerable of Entities.

To fix it - try something like:

```
e => e.Entities.Take(offset).Count() > 3
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you've forgotten to declare your method as generic. so, instead of

```
... GetWithNChildren(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null)
```

You should have:

```
GetWithNChildren<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null)
```

Comment: He would be getting a diffrent error if that was the case, T is likely defined on the class level.

Comment: Thanks Scott, that may be true. ;-)